# WCF Data Service using custom UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, authorization, wcf-data-services

I am trying to setup a WCF Data Service to use my custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` it is working great for standard WCF Services; the problem I have is this: In my web.config I cannot specify the WCF Data Service endpoint because it does not implement a contract I can use. See below

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="GetHttpsIncludeFaults" name="WCFDataService">
    <endpoint
        address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHTTP"
        Contract="WHAT-GOES-HERE?"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <behavior name="GetHttpsIncludeFaults">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="204800" />
    <serviceCredentials>
      <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="pjt.UPValidate, pjt"/>
    </serviceCredentials>
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
```

For my normal WCF services, I simply sepcify the interface that the class implements; with Data Services I have no such interface.

If there is a better way to customize the `ServiceBehavior` I'm open to that, this is just the only way I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of poking around, I was able to get a new error by using this contract: `System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler`.

After getting past the error that the contract was not implemented by my service, it seems as if WCF Data Services only work with webHttpBinding -- which does not support TransportWithmessageCredential security.

So, this doesn't exactly answer my question; however, this appears to be the only way to secure a WCF Data Service via a custom username / password validator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx

It involves using BASIC authentication, and writing your own HttpModule to have IIS delegate the authentication to your own custom username password validator. Obviously, this should only be used over HTTPS.